# How to remap ports using Docker (Docker-toolbox) runing on windows7?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I am trying to do some port remapping when running docker image. like this: docker run -p 3000:3000 . And i dont get any response from localhost:3000

Inside img i have a small test app. with code like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('***** Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function () {
   console.log('****** Example app listening on port 3000! *****');
})
```

Issue is that i dont have any response from localhost:3000

Docker file:

```
FROM node:alpine
COPY ./web ./
COPY ./ ./
RUN cd web
RUN npm i
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: please add to your question the Dockerfile. Start the the container with `docker run -it -p 3000:3000 image-name` and after you start the container run `docker container ls -a` and put the output of both in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately port remaping is not working with docker on win7 like on any linux environment. What is happening :
Port is remaped, but not regarding localhost, but regarding ip of VM
So, instead of localhost: we should use :port